# Step function without piece wise definition

Tags: functions, special-functions, piecewise-continuity

Usually I would think of a step function in terms of a piece wise definition:

$$U(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \ge a\\ 0 & x < a\end{cases}$$

Can I write it in a way that does not require a piece wise definition or logic statements? For example, you could write the absolute value function in a way that does not require conditional statements by defining $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$. 
Similarly, you can get the min or max of two numbers without using logic operations by following:
[How to calculate Maximum or Minimum of two numbers without using if?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58792/how-to-calculate-maximum-or-minimum-of-two-numbers-without-using-if)
I'm looking for the same idea but for the step function. Wikipedia has some continuous approximations, and also alternative definitions like the integral of a Dirac delta function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function, but I'm wondering if there is anything simpler?

Comment: What is your criterion for simplicity?

Comment: If you do not care about the value at $x = 0$, then you can simply use the expression $$ \frac{1}{2}(1 + \operatorname{sign}(x)) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} \right). $$

Answer (score 1):

Modification of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169917/given-n-what-function-returns-0-for-n-1-but-1-for-all-else/1169938#1169938):

$$U_a(x)=\left\lfloor4\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(x+1-a)+\pi}{5\pi}\right\rfloor$$

edit: Here's another

$$U'_a(x)=\left\lfloor \dfrac{2^{x-a}-2^{-x+a}}{2^{x-a}+2^{-x+a}}+1\right\rfloor $$

Comment: It is an elementary function, by definition. A synonym for elementary is simple.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that arctan is not simple. However I've posted an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using derivatives, you can write $$U_a(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}|x-a|,$$ and, as you noted, $|x-a| = \sqrt{(x-a)^2}$. Of course, this fails to be defined at $x=a$, so is not quite the same as your "$U_a(x) = 1 \text{ if } x\geq a$."