# Rewrite a piecewise function into a single expression

Tags: functions, piecewise-continuity

Consider a piecewise function . I want a general way to rewrite it , into the single expression . I know that for sign function there is a single expression but I'm looking for solve it generally.

Answer (score 2):

It is not always possible, and many of the times it *is* possible, it's only because we're hiding the piecewise definition behind a dedicated piece of notation. For instance, the function $f(x)=|x|$ is really the function
$$
f(x)=\cases{x&if $x\geq0$\\-x&if $x<0$}
$$It's just that this particular piecewise function is *so common* that we have established a specific piece of notation to make writing the function easier.

Comment: For example what about this ? $x \lt 0 \to y = 0$ and $x \gt 0 \to y =1$

Comment: Normally write this $f(x) = \chi_{\{x>0\}}(x)$

Comment: $$y = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{|x|}+1\right)$$

Comment: @Jack Can you explain what is this ? $f(x) = \xi_{x>0}(x)$

Comment: @quasi I think it is wrong for $x \lt 0$

Comment: @S.H.W The function $\chi$ is defined by $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. Other people denote it by $\mathbb 1_A$

Comment: @S.H.W -- fixed now

Comment: @Jack But it is a piecewise function again !

Comment: @S.H.W -- You didn't define $y$ when $x = 0$. What do you want it to be?

Comment: @quasi It's not important when $x=0$.

Comment: @S.H.W this might help - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903741/step-function-without-piece-wise-definition?rq=1

Comment: @Jack Thank you a lot . They were very complicated functions . I don't know how he gets it !

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments, you asked for a function, defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R},\,$ such that
$$
f(x)=\cases{
0 &\text{if}\; x < 0\\[3pt]
1 &\text{if}\; x > 0
}
$$
Here's one trick which will bury the cases . . .

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor{\max\left(0\,,\frac{1+x}{1+|x|}\right)}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: But I think it is wrong because for $x \gt 0 $ we have $f(x) = 0$

Comment: Sorry , I edited .

Comment: For the function I posted, for $x \ge 0$, we have $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: The max of $0,1$ is $1$, and the floor of $1$ is $1$.

Comment: Okay so you should use curly brackets instead of parenthesis.

Comment: Because I just think that it means an interval .

Comment: No$\,-\,$parentheses are correct. The function $\max$ is a function of two variables. By definition, $\max(a,b)$ equals $a$ or $b$, whichever is greater.

Comment: Okay but I see it usually with curly brackets . It's fine no problem thank you a lot!